# clarification about indefinite integral being a primitive

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

In the page $211$ of Tom Apostol's Calculus Vol-$1$, it is written, **"the first fundamental theorem states that any indefinite integral of $f$ is also a primitive of $f$."**

I suppose that holds only for a function $f$ which is continuous on the interval of integration (which is also the domain of the primitive function)?

Thanks!

Comment: In the page preceding that one, where the section begins, he says “If $f$ is continuous on an interval, one primitive is given by…” It seems to me that Apostol is indeed assuming $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Exactly. But I'd like to get an answer from someone who is certain about that, so I'm not missing something.

Comment: I liked your answer, so I'm not sure why it was deleted. It gave a nice counter example if the above was correct without continuity condition on f. [The only thing was that Apostol didn't use mean value theorem for the full proof of the FTC, and he required only a single point continuity, rather than a neighborhood continuity in the actual analytic proof.]

Comment: You are correct. I deleted my answer because I made assumptions about what Apostol said that weren’t true when I looked at the book again. Sorry!

Comment: The example you gave was similar to what I had in mind when thinking about the mentioned sentence. For example, a floor function is integrable, but it's integral is not differentiable on the whole interval (i.e. at the integer values), so it cannot be the primitive of the integrand. I tend to think that the connection between integration and primitives really makes sense only for continuous integrands. However, I do not have enough confidence in my understanding to just declare that Apostol was not precise when writing the above sentence, so I expect others have the confidence.

Comment: You have the right idea in looking for counterexamples. The floor function and the function I came up with have something in common: removable/jump discontinuities. It turns out that the derivative of a function cannot have any such discontinuities! So if it isn’t a derivative, how can it have a primitive? That’s the idea.